# Custom Control - How to add a converter to the existing control?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I have a third party control. I want to add some specific behavior to this control which could be reusable to any part of my project. Certainly, custom control is the option to go for. However, I'm not sure what is the best way to provide a new Converter to the Custom Control which is built on the top of the existing control. Could someone please help me with this?

The control which I'm trying to override belongs to the third party and I want to provide a Converter for one of the ItemControl this control is using in its DataTemplate. I can easily identify the place where I need to specify the new Converter in XAML, but how to specify this through code in order to create Custom Control is daunting me. The challenge for me is to how to get the property in code behind for binding. The Converter will remain static for all the clients except a string which will be passed as a Converter Parameter that I want to be submitted by every referring code.

Following is the code snippet of the DataTemplate -

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="{themes:PdfViewerThemeKey ResourceKey=PdfPrintEditorTemplate}">
        <Grid>                
            <dxlc:DockLayoutControl x:Name="PART_DockLayoutControl" AllowItemSizing="True" Margin="5">
                <dxlc:LayoutGroup x:Name="PART_DockPreviewPart" Orientation="Vertical" dxlc:DockLayoutControl.Dock="Left" Margin="5" Width="427">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <dxe:ImageEdit x:Name="PART_ImagePreview" ShowMenu="False" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,10" EditValue="{Binding Path=PdfViewModel.PreviewImageBytes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" Width="427" Height="518"/>                            
                    </Grid>
                </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                <dxlc:LayoutGroup x:Name="PART_DockClientPart" ItemLabelsAlignment="Local" MinWidth="425" Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical" dxlc:DockLayoutControl.Dock="Client" dxlc:DockLayoutControl.AllowHorizontalSizing="True">
                    <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="{Binding Source={x:Null}, Converter={StaticResource PdfViewerStringIdConverter}, ConverterParameter=PrintDialogPrinterName}" AddColonToLabel="True">
                        <dxlc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <dxlc:LayoutItem VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <dxe:ComboBoxEdit Margin="5,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PdfViewModel.PrinterItems}" ApplyItemTemplateToSelectedItem="True" IsTextEditable="False" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=PdfViewModel.PrinterIndex}">
                                    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <dxe:ImageEdit ShowBorder="False" Source="{Binding Path=PrinterType, Converter={StaticResource printerTypeToImageConverter}}"/>
                                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,2,4,2" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
                                </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>                                    
                            </dxlc:LayoutItem>                                
                        </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                    </dxlc:LayoutItem>

                </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
            </dxlc:DockLayoutControl>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Please let me know the best way to implement this.

Comment: I've added the XAML in the main question. There is control called ComboBoxEdit. I want to provide the Converter for its ItemSource property which is currently bind to "PdfViewModel.PrinterItems" property.

Comment: Are you trying to apply a converter to `PdfViewModel.PrinterItems` to convert the collection, or to each item in the collection?   Is this a use case for DataTemplates?

Comment: I wish to apply a Converter to the collection, not the individual items. What do you mean by use case here? I didn't get that.

Comment: I misunderstood originally, DataTemplates wouldn't help here.  I think what you're trying to do is set the `ItemsSource` of your `ComboBoxEdit` in code behind using a converter?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to set the converter in the XAML itself?  (e.g. `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PdfViewModel.PrinterItems, Converter=...}"`?

Comment: I can do that and solve the problem for now. But what I'm trying to make it is a Custom Control, so that it can be used anywhere. That Custom Control will take a string as input through either a Constructor or public dependency property which will be used by the converter to filter the items in the collection to be displayed in the ComboBoxEdit control.

Comment: Do you have any code for the custom control that currently exists?

Comment: No. I don't have any code for the Custom Control as of now.